# Smoothing kernel on Hough transform?

Tags: c++, smoothing

I have an array containing votes (from a Hough transform) of where there are circles in data, I have collected. How would I go about smoothing the data?

This is an example I have made so far (the data is much bigger and impossible to get an overview of). I tried doing what I thought was a kernel smoother, but it might not be what I thought it was.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    double data[20][20];        // Unsmoothed array
    double smoothed[20][20];    // Output array
    double kernel[3][3];        // Kernel for smoothing

    kernel[0][0] = 0.05;
    kernel[0][1] = 0.1;
    kernel[0][2] = 0.05;
    kernel[1][0] = 0.1;
    kernel[1][1] = 0.8;
    kernel[1][2] = 0.1;
    kernel[2][0] = 0.05;
    kernel[2][1] = 0.1;
    kernel[2][2] = 0.05;

    double factor = (double)5 / (double)7; // To normalize the kernel
    double counter = 0.0;

    for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            data[i][j] = counter;   // Elements go from 0 to 299
            smoothed[i][j] = 0;     // Set all elements to zero
            counter++;
        }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            if (i > 0 && j > 0 && i < 19 && j < 19)
            {
                smoothed[i][j] = (
                    kernel[0][0] * data[i - 1][j - 1] +
                    kernel[0][1] * data[i    ][j - 1] +
                    kernel[0][2] * data[i + 1][j - 1] +
                    kernel[1][0] * data[i - 1][j    ] +
                    kernel[1][1] * data[i    ][j    ] +
                    kernel[1][2] * data[i + 1][j    ] +
                    kernel[2][0] * data[i - 1][j + 1] +
                    kernel[2][1] * data[i    ][j + 1] +
                    kernel[2][2] * data[i + 1][j + 1]
                    ) * factor;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            std::cout << smoothed[i][j] << "    ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

However, this produces the same output as the input - with the exception of having cut off the edge of the data, but that's not a problem with my data anyway.

Is this a completely wrong way to do it, or am I just missing some details?

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Okay, I apologize then. I'm just not sure I have understood the theory of smoothing, and that's mostly why I wanted some feedback, to see if I was completely off.

Comment: Also, isn't the code I have included minimal, complete, and verifiable? It is precisely a boiled down version of my program that shows what I'm asking about.

Comment: You should at least give the people that have Eigen installed, a chance to just copy your code into their IDE, press the _compile button_ and start debugging it. But IMO, the debugging efforts is on your site 1st. You code won't ever compile with statements outside of function scope blocks, etc.

Comment: I rewrote the example to not use Eigen now. Should I delete this thread and make a new?

Comment: As mentioned debug it on your own 1st please. If you see specific anomalies, explain them and come back (with this very question).

Comment: It actually does blur (only slightly, because this kernel is very peaked), but the test data is already smooth - if you plot it as a plane in 3D it is actually a plane. With different data it becomes clear that it blurs, eg [this](http://ideone.com/GbHRKA)